# Autohotkey escape quotes in string (for Run command arguments)

Tags: windows, cmd, autohotkey

I'm trying to pass arguments to a windows command via autohotkey, but I haven't been able to successfully escape quotes in the string.

I want to do something like:
Run, shutdown "/s /c /"MESSAGE/""

So I run the command:
shutdown /s /c "MESSAGE"

How do I do this?

Comment: What's not working?  It looks correct to me...  AutoHotkey groups things that have quotes around them into one parameter.  `a b "c d"` would be three parameters; the third being "c d".  The quotes just aren't passed literally, because programs expect a list of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Double up the quotes to escape them.

```
Run, shutdown "/s /c ""MESSAGE"""
```

See the [EscapeChar](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_EscapeChar.htm) documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The forward slash is not an escape key so you don't need to escape it, if you have problems put curly braces around it like : `shutdown {/}f {/}r {/}t 00 {Enter}`  but it should work (and does on my machine) without curly braces.  The quotes can also be done inside curly braces.  So:  `shutdown /s /c {"}MESSAGE{"}` should work.